# Python return not

Tags: python-3.x

Please could anybody help me to understand the meaning of this piece of code?

```
def isNotHeader(line: str):
    return not (line.startswith("host") and "bytes" in line)
```

Comment: The keyword ```not``` just means the opposite of what you are doing. Once you figure out what this line does ```(line.startswith("host") and "bytes" in line)```, you will know what is the opposite of it.

Answer (score 1):

The `return not` just returns false if it satisfies the given condition.

Example:

```py
In [7]: def isNotHeader(line: str):
   ...:     return not (line.startswith("host") and "bytes" in line)
   ...: 

In [8]: isNotHeader("host bytes 1")
Out[8]: False

In [9]: isNotHeader("has bytes 1")
Out[9]: True

In [10]: isNotHeader("host no-bits 1")
Out[10]: True
```

`line.startswith("host")` - Basically checks if the string starts with this keyword `host`

`"bytes" in line` - Checks if the string `'bytes'` exists in the line
In the second case `line8` you see that since it satisfies the condition of line it returns `False` and in the other case `line9` it returns `True` as it does not satisfy the condition. The condition basically  returns a boolean truth value which could be either False or True based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

that line just means the funstion should return the opposite of whatever boolean value it evauates to, for Example:

```
def retTrue():
    return 2==2
```

will return True, because 2 equal to 2 is true, but:

```
def retNot():
    return not 2==2
```

will return False, because, although 2 equal to 2 is true, you've told python to return the OPPOSITE of whatever it evaluates

so if the line starts with the string "host" i.e. `line.startswith("host")` and the string "bytes" is somewhere in the line, you'd ordinarily have a `True` evaluation but since there's a `not` it flips it to a `False`

Answer (score 0):

This is a function `isNotHeader` which takes an argument named `line` which has to be a string (`str` type).
It returns boolean (`bool` type) - `True` or `False`.

It returns opposite (because of `not`) value of this expression: `line.startswith("host") and "bytes" in line`.

`line.startswith("host")` checks if at the beginning of the string there is a string `"host"`. If there is, it returns `True`.

`"bytes" in line` checks if in the string there is a continuous string `"bytes"`. If there is, it returns `True`.

If both expressions (`line.startswith("host")` and `"bytes" in line`) are `True`, the line `line.startswith("host") and "bytes" in line` is `True` and the function `isNotHeader` returns `False` (because of `not` before the expression).
If any of them (`line.startswith("host")` and `"bytes" in line`) are `False`, the line `line.startswith("host") and "bytes" in line` is `False` and the function `isNotHeader` returns `True`